# bison/flex on sql parsing : user entered column name was a keyword

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I am parsing a sql-like language using bison/flex. If the user entered a column name and it happened was a token/keyword, I got "syntax error". How to do an error handling properly ? For example, the 'from' is a keyword, it should not be used.  The customized action code does not work, because the error was raised before the action was invoked.

```
 create table stayIn (
 from date,
 to date);
```

Comment: What you show there isn't valid SQL syntax. You can't use keywords like `from` and `to` as column names without escaping them by putting them in double-quotes. This is for ANSI-SQL - other dialects may use different escape characters.

Comment: You *are* doing it 'properly'. It's a syntax error.

Comment: To be clear, is the point to get your parser to accept this as valid SQL, or is it to get your parser to give a better error message than "syntax error"? The other commenters seem to have interpreted it as the former. If they are right, I agree with them, but my interpretation leans to the latter.

Comment: @hdv Try a similar thing in a C or Java compiler. You'll get 'syntax error', not anything corresponding to 'you can't use a keyword here'. This is not how parsers work, and particularly not generated parsers.

Comment: @hdv  You are correct, I need a better error handling than "syntax error".

Comment: @EJP Proper error handling is part of how parsers work. What C or Java compiler are you using that, when encountering a syntax error, doesn't provide any more info than "syntax error"? The bare minimum that should be trivial to implement is "syntax error: unexpected keyword FROM". This would at least point the user to the fact that "from" was interpreted as a keyword rather than a column name.

Comment: @user3658306 You can't get it out of *yacc* or *bison*. The best you can get is ainaccurate (slightly too large) list of tokens that are valid at the current point of the parse.

Comment: @hvd You can certainly get 'unexpected token XXX', but you can't get anything amounting to 'you can't use a keyword as a column name'. The mechanics of LALR(1) parsing prevent it.

Comment: @EJP You can extend the syntax and then treat it as a semantic error, but yeah, you probably shouldn't. The "unexpected token (...)" might be enough for what the OP is after, though. OP, could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

About the best you can do without major surgery is to add the current input token `yytext` to the message, or a line/column number if you keep track of those in your lexer, or both. So you would get something like

```
syntax error near 'from'
```

or

```
syntax error, line 3, column 1
```

or both. Just adapt `yyerror()` like this:

```
int yyerror(char *message)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s" near "%s", message, yytext);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I have so many keywords, I cannot make the if statement in the bison rule action like this "if(($1).compare("from") && if (($1).compare("to") &&......." yyerror().